# Extreme points of set of probability measures $\mathcal{P}= \{F: \int_{\mathbb{R}} |x|^k dF(x)=c \}$

Tags: measure-theory, convexity

I am interested in finding the extreme points of the following set of distributions 
\begin{align}
\mathcal{P}= \left\{F: \int_{\mathbb{R}} |x|^k dF(x)=c \right\}
\end{align}
where $k,c>0$.

I know that [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/3689944.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3A6c1f2a909f95192f8b30edf1e31ad3de) by Winkler is a standard reference on this question.

I was trying to extract the answer from this paper and got that the set of extreme points is given by 
\begin{align}
\mathop{\rm ex}(\mathcal{P}) = \left\{F \in \mathcal{P} : F= (1-t) \delta_{x_1}+t \delta_{x_2}, t\in[0,1], x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb{R} \right\}.
\end{align}

However, not sure if this is correct since in [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/85527/extreme-points-of-a-set-of-probability-measures), for a very similar set, it was pointed out that it must be combination of three mass points instead of two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the paper asserts in this case is $ex\mathcal P=\{F:F=(1-t)\delta_{x}+t\delta_y, t\in[0,1], (1-t)|x|^k+t|y|^k=c, x+y\neq0\}$. This includes singletons $\delta_x$ with $|x|^k=c$.

What was pointed out is not the existence of three-point masses as extreme points, but that the proof (that only convex combinations of two point masses are extreme) was obvious for probability measures on a three point set instead of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: A ok. Thanks. Can you explain where the condition $x +y \neq 0$ is coming from?  Is this from the linear independence?

Comment: Yes. Take $c=1$. Then $\delta_1$ and $\delta_{-1}$ are extreme, but not $(1-t)\delta_1+t\delta_{-1}$ since it is a convex combination of them.

Comment: I have one more question.  Do you know what are the extreme points of as set of probability measures with a bounded support?  That is set to $\mathcal{P}=\{  F: |{\rm supp}(F)| \le A\}$

Comment: If you mean a support of at most $A$ points, the set of such probability measures is not convex. If you mean $\supp(F)\subset A$, the set is convex with $\delta_a,a\in A$ as extreme points.

Comment: Sorry the was very bad notation.  I mean distributions supported on the bounded interval of reals. All $F$ such that  $F([a,b])=1$. I vaguely remember that it should be a set of singletons.

Comment: Please see the question I asked here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/278196/extreme-points-of-a-set-of-distributions-with-moment-and-or-support-constraint

Comment: I know that this is an old question, but I have one more quick question. The above result also holds for $\mathbb{R}^n$ where $n>1$, right?